# How to get the number of cluster on the SOM plot, in each of the node?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, som

I want to understand to which node my wine is connected after getting a som plot.

That's why firstly we need to get data.frame with the name of wine and the number of cluster that wines belongs to. And next step would be to see the number of the cluster on this plot. But idk how:)

```
data(wines)
View(wines)    
#adding id for each wine

wines<-as.data.frame(wines)
wines$ID <- seq.int(nrow(wines))

#substract the id to know the "name" of wine

som_wines<-wines[,-14]
som_model<-som(scale(som_wines), grid = somgrid(5, 5, "hexagonal"))
som_codes<-as.data.frame(som_model$codes)

#ilustrating needed quantity of clusters

mydata <- as.data.frame(som_model$codes)
wss <- (nrow(mydata)-1)*sum(apply(mydata,2,var)) 
for (i in 2:15) {
  wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(mydata, centers=i)$withinss)
}
plot(wss)

#som plot

som_cluster <- cutree(hclust(dist(som_codes)), 3)
plot(som_model, type="codes",bgcol= som_cluster, main = "Clusters") 
add.cluster.boundaries(som_model, som_cluster)   ` 

#Here we got 3 clusters. Creating the dataframe which defines wines id's to cluster groups.

cluster_details <- data.frame(id=wines$ID, cluster=som_cluster[som_model$unit.classif])
```

And now I want numbers of clusters to be shown there, on the som plot. Are there any suggestions how to cope with that? Would appreciate any answer :)

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you simply want to write the text "Three clusters" on the graph?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: no, I want to know coordinates of every wine. To be more clear we have map 5*5, and 163 id's of wine, and I want to know to which node that wine belongs. I mean some of them would be lying in [1,2] node, some in [3,4] (if first number is x axis and second is y axis), and those wines belong to a different clusters, and I want to see where each wine particularly situated ( not only to know the number of cluster they belong, but also their coordinates on the map) to understand visually what behavior they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is situated here: [add clusters and nodes from SOMbrero package to training data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843491/add-clusters-and-nodes-from-sombrero-package-to-training-data)

Particularly in these lines :

```
SomModel <- som(
    data = TrainingMatrix,
    grid = GridDefinition,
    rlen = 10000,
    alpha = c(0.05, 0.01),
    keep.data = TRUE
)

nb <- table(SomModel$unit.classif)
groups = 5
tree.hc = cutree(hclust(d=dist(SomModel$codes[[1]]),method="ward.D2",members=nb),groups)


result <- OrginalData
result$Cluster <- tree.hc[SomModel$unit.classif]
result$X <- SomModel$grid$pts[SomModel$unit.classif,"x"]
result$Y <- SomModel$grid$pts[SomModel$unit.classif,"y"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check to what node each observation belongs to by calling the model's variable namely unit.classif.
Based on your scripts, you assign the model to som_model. Therefore, you can call

```
som_model$unit.classif
```

The vector is ordered by the row order of your data, i.e. your 1st input data belongs to the node denoted by the 1st unit.classif vector value, and so on.
You can check by calling

```
length(som_model$unit.classif)
nrow(som_wines)
```

They have the same length.
The library arrange the nodes in a matrix whose number of dimension of (nodes x features).
If you define your model to have 5x5 nodes, whilst your data have 13 features, so your model's node would be denoted as a 25x13 matrix.
You chan check by calling

```
dim(som_model$codes[[1]])
```

On the map, the nodes line up from bottom left to top right. The first node is on the bottom left and the 25th node is on the top right of the codes map.
So if you want to know the position of the node to which a particular data belongs to, you can extend your script to something like this:

```
from.bottom <- ceiling(som_model$unit.classif / som_model$grid$xdim)
from.left <- som_model$unit.classif %% som_model$grid$xdim
from.left[from.left == 0] <-  som_model$grid$xdim

cluster_details <- cbind(
  cluster_details, som.unit = som_model$unit.classif,
  from.bottom = from.bottom, from.left = from.left
)

(cluster_details)
```